# Vue - getting an array as a json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, axios

I am sending an array of objects from the backend to the Vue frontend that looks like this in the postman:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 112,
        "menu_order": 1,
        "title": "Nyheter",
        "slug": "hjem",
        "url": "/nyheter",
        "status": "publish",
        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
    },
    {
        "ID": 159,
        "menu_order": 2,
        "title": "HivNorge mener",
        "slug": "hivnorge-mener",
        "url": "/post/bli-frivillig",
        "status": "publish",
        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
    },
    {
        "ID": 160,
        "menu_order": 3,
        "submenu": [
            {
                "ID": 3307,
                "menu_order": 4,
                "title": "Hva er hiv?",
                "slug": "hva-er-hiv",
                "url": "/post/hva-er-hiv",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3292,
                "menu_order": 5,
                "title": "Hva er aids?",
                "slug": "hva-er-aids",
                "url": "/post/hva-er-aids",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3280,
                "menu_order": 6,
                "title": "Hivtesten",
                "slug": "hivtesten",
                "url": "/post/hivtesten",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 6308,
                "menu_order": 7,
                "title": "PEP og PrEP",
                "slug": "pep-og-prep",
                "url": "/post/pep-og-prep",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3252,
                "menu_order": 8,
                "title": "Smitteveier",
                "slug": "smitteveier",
                "url": "/post/smitteveier",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 6610,
                "menu_order": 9,
                "title": "Nye retningslinjer for hivbehandling",
                "slug": "nye-retningslinjer-for-hivbehandling",
                "url": "/post/nye-retningslinjer-for-hivbehandling",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 7172,
                "menu_order": 10,
                "title": "Quiz",
                "slug": "quiz",
                "url": "/type/quiz",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 145,
                "menu_order": 11,
                "submenu": [
                    {
                        "ID": 5141,
                        "menu_order": 12,
                        "title": "Straffeloven",
                        "slug": "straffeloven-2",
                        "url": "/post/straffeloven-1",
                        "status": "publish",
                        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Hiv og juss",
                "slug": "hiv-og-juss",
                "url": "/folder/hiv-og-juss",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3040,
                "menu_order": 13,
                "submenu": [
                    {
                        "ID": 3474,
                        "menu_order": 14,
                        "title": "Kriminalisering",
                        "slug": "kriminalisering",
                        "url": "/post/kriminalisering-2",
                        "status": "publish",
                        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 4017,
                        "menu_order": 15,
                        "title": "FN og aids",
                        "slug": "fn-og-aids",
                        "url": "/post/fn-og-aids",
                        "status": "publish",
                        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 3971,
                        "menu_order": 16,
                        "title": "Kort historie",
                        "slug": "kort-historie",
                        "url": "/post/kort-historie",
                        "status": "publish",
                        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Hiv i verden",
                "slug": "hiv-i-verden",
                "url": "/folder/hiv-i-verden",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3088,
                "menu_order": 17,
                "title": "Statistikk",
                "slug": "statistikk",
                "url": "/post/statistikk-2",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3102,
                "menu_order": 18,
                "title": "Andres materiell",
                "slug": "andres-materiell",
                "url": "/post/andres-materiell",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 5667,
                "menu_order": 19,
                "title": "Andres aktiviteter",
                "slug": "andres-aktiviteter",
                "url": "/post/andres-aktiviteter",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            }
        ],
        "title": "Om hiv",
        "slug": "om-hivaids",
        "url": "/folder/om-hiv",
        "status": "publish",
        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
    },
    {
        "ID": 3050,
        "menu_order": 20,
        "submenu": [
            {
                "ID": 3310,
                "menu_order": 21,
                "title": "Sekretariatet",
                "slug": "sekretariatet",
                "url": "/post/sekretariatet",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3296,
                "menu_order": 22,
                "title": "Styret",
                "slug": "styret",
                "url": "/post/styret",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 4449,
                "menu_order": 23,
                "title": "Strategiplan",
                "slug": "strategiplan",
                "url": "/post/strategiplan",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3276,
                "menu_order": 24,
                "title": "Vedtekter",
                "slug": "vedtekter",
                "url": "/post/vedtekter",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3235,
                "menu_order": 25,
                "title": "Årsmeldinger",
                "slug": "arsmeldinger",
                "url": "/post/aarsmeldinger",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3211,
                "menu_order": 26,
                "title": "Medlemmer",
                "slug": "medlemmer",
                "url": "/post/medlemmer",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3156,
                "menu_order": 27,
                "title": "Her er vi",
                "slug": "her-er-vi",
                "url": "/post/her-er-vi",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 5355,
                "menu_order": 28,
                "title": "Historie",
                "slug": "historie-2",
                "url": "/post/historie-1",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3254,
                "menu_order": 29,
                "title": "Retningslinjer",
                "slug": "retningslinjer",
                "url": "/post/retningslinjer",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 5486,
                "menu_order": 30,
                "title": "Gave",
                "slug": "gave",
                "url": "/post/gave",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            {
                "ID": 5781,
                "menu_order": 31,
                "title": "Bli frivillig",
                "slug": "bli-frivillig",
                "url": "/post/bli-frivillig",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            }
        ],
        "title": "Om oss",
        "slug": "om-oss",
        "url": "/folder/om-oss",
        "status": "publish",
        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
    }
]
```

I am using Axios for ajax requests, what I don't get is why is this array interpreted as an object when I get it in the frontend. When I am making a call to the backend:

```
     BACKEND.get('/menu')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        commit('setMenus', res.data);
      })
```

In the console `res.data` I get an object that consist of objects that are elements of the array above, what I get looks like this, (it is a very stripped down example):

```
{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 13: {…}}
1:Object
  ID:7406
  main_category:"Hovedmeny"
  menu_order:1
  slug:"nyheter"
  title:"Nyheter"
  url:"/nyheter"
 ...so on
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: that's pretty interesting. Technically arrays in javascript are objects (do `typeof` on any array to see this). When you get data in an ajax response it is normally a JSON string, which the JS interpreter converts to a JSON object. If I had to guess this is just the JS interpreter mistakenly assuming the array should be presented as an object. Are you converting the data to a string before sending it or are you letting the server handle that for you?

Comment: well, if I do ```console.log(Array.isArray(res.data));```I get false

Comment: of course, because it's already been shaped as an object. If you aren't stringifying before you send it then try that. If you are stringifying it then try padding it, wrap it in an object with a property called data, and put your array in that data property. Then access it as `res.data.data`